# mod rewrite in apache server and htaccess file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

what is the difference between 
`mod_rewrite.so` and `mod_rewrite.c` in Apache server ? In .htaccess file also we should write `mod_rewrite.so` or `mod_rewrite.c` ?

Answer (score 0):

In Apache 2.x, it's normal to just use the .so. For example:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

In Apache 1.x it was necessary to `AddModule module.c` after loading the shared library .so.